# R remove duplicate value in one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data in the form:

```
column1                    column2
milk,cheese,eggs         milk,cheese,sugar 
cheese, eggs             milk,water
eggs, milk               milk, water, juice
```

I want to remove all instances of duplicates of milk in column2. That is, if milk exists in both columns in a row, remove milk from column2. So the output should ideally read as follows:

```
column1                    column2
milk,cheese,eggs         cheese,sugar 
cheese, eggs             milk,water
eggs, milk               water, juice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to identify if `'milk'` is present in `column1` and remove it from `column2` using `gsub`.

```
inds <- grepl('milk', df$column1)
df$column2[inds] <- gsub('milk', '', df$column2[inds])
#Remove additional commas in the text if present
df$column2 <- gsub(',{2,}', '', trimws(df$column2, whitespace = ','))
df

#           column1      column2
#1 milk,cheese,eggs cheese,sugar
#2      cheese,eggs   milk,water
#3        eggs,milk  water,juice
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(column1 = c("milk,cheese,eggs", "cheese,eggs", 
"eggs,milk"), column2 = c("milk,cheese,sugar", "milk,water", 
"milk,water,juice")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```